# uploading file in java via php

Tags: java, php

i'm trying to upload a file on my php server using java,but my httprequest fails every time i run the code,i don't know what is its cause,first i thought it may be caused by the multipartEnttity method whose parameters i left empty earlier,but now after filling it the same problem still ocurrs....

```
    //this is my java code

    String path="E:\\upload.txt";
    HttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();
    hc.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpPost hp=new HttpPost("http://localhost/shoolPHP/uploadFile.php");
    File f=new File(path);
    MultipartEntity me=new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    ContentBody cf=new FileBody(f);
    me.addPart("userfile", cf);
    hp.setEntity(me);
    System.out.println("executing request" +hp.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse hr=hc.execute(hp);
    HttpEntity he=hr.getEntity();

    if(!(hr.getStatusLine().toString()).equals("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")){
        System.out.println("Uploaded");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Failed");


    }
    System.out.println(hr.getStatusLine());
    if (he != null) {
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(he));
    }
    if (he != null) {
        he.consumeContent();
    }
    hc.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

//this is corrected php code

```
  <?php

  $uploads_dir='/Home';
  if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])){
   $dest=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  echo "File" .$_FILES['userfile']['name'] ."uploaded file successfully to
  $uploads_dir/$dest";

  move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['userfile'] ['tmp_name'],  "$uploads_dir/$dest");
  } else {
  echo "Possible file upload attack: ";
  echo "filename '". $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] . "'.";
  print_r($_FILES);
  }
  ?>
```

//these are the new warnings

executing requestPOST http://localhost/shoolPHP/uploadFile.php HTTP/1.1
Uploaded
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Fileupload.txtuploaded file successfully to
/Home/upload.txt
**Warning**:  move_uploaded_file(/Home/upload.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\shoolPHP\uploadFile.php** on line **9**

**Warning**:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB374.tmp' to '/Home/upload.txt' in **C:\xampp\htdocs\shoolPHP\uploadFile.php** on line **9**

Comment: Have you read the error messages and looked at the lines they refer to? This is basic syntax checking.

Comment: corrected the 'Files' miss spell  but still problem exists

Comment: Well, you're trying to access a folder `/Home/` on your Windows machine. Could you explain what folder you think that should be? Does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

Your code says:

```
if(!(hr.getStatusLine().toString()).equals("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")){
  ^^^
   +--- Notice the ! (not)
```

Change that to:

```
if((hr.getStatusLine().toString()).equals("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")){
```

The upload *did go alright* if the status is 200, so it has to *equal* that status line to say "Uploaded". Your code said it had to be different from that to say "Uploaded"

Comment: So you have a warning; that's not an error. Does the file upload work?